# Draw a line above a docked control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a borderless form that I'm "docking" onto the top edge of my screen. Inside of the form, I'm placing a single toolstrip control, which docks across the entire form -> (picture the taskbar to get an idea of what I'm talking about).

Because the borderless form has no edge to it, I wanted to draw a black line along the bottom edg` of the form to differentiate the form from the windows or desktop behind it.

The problem that I'm facing is that`the toolstrip will not move "behind" the line when it's docked, no matter how I order the control layers.

I've tried programatically sending the control to back to no avail either.

Any ideas on how to get the line to show above the docked toolstrip?

Comment: What is with crazy use of code formatting?  Those are not code snippets or keywords.  Those edits made the post harder to read, not easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dock another control to the top that displays like a black line (e.g. a Label with a black background and a height of 1). Insert your ToolStrip after you have docked the Label. It will dock just below the Label.